# Why are the images in my popup all different height? CSS Issue

Tags: css, popup, photo

If you visit this link and have a look at the 4 photos in the popup, you will notice they are gradually getting shorter as they go right.
https://jadehomes.ca/floor-plans/?virtual-tour

I have messed around with several CSS properties, including display:, height:, and max-width:, but none of them seem to be the issue.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
.spu-box img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need change:

```
.spu-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

or

```
.spu-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because the photos won't be responsive on all screen sizes.